# Galois theory problem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ and $L$ be Galois extensions of $k$, contained in an extension $M$ of $k$ ( so that $KL$ makes sense).

1. Show that if $K\cap L=k$, then $\operatorname{Gal}(KL/k)\cong \operatorname{Gal}(K/k)\times \operatorname{Gal}(L/k)$.
2. Using this show that if $\operatorname{char}(k)\neq 2$ and $K/k$ is a non cyclic Galois extension of degree $4$, then there are $u,v\in k$ such that $K=k(\sqrt u +\sqrt v)$.
3. Show more generally if $\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group, then $K$ is a composite of quadratic extensions of $k$.

I have done part (1). How do you establish parts 2 and 3?

Thank you so much for your help and time.

Answer (score 3):

- This is a common fact. Show more generally that

$$\text{Gal}(LK/k)=\left\{(\sigma,\tau)\in\text{Gal}(L/k)\times\text{Gal}(K/k):\sigma\mid_{K\cap L}=\tau\mid_{K\cap L}\right\}$$

But, you said you've already done this.

- Well, you know that $\text{Gal}(K/k)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (why?). So, taking the two subgroups corresponding to the two factors $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ produces two subextensions $K/L,L'/k$ with $[L:k]=[L':k]=2$ (why?). Since $\text{char}(k)\ne 2$ you know that $L=k(\sqrt{u})$ and $L'=k(\sqrt{v})$ for some $u,v\in k$ (why?). Note that since the intersection of the two subgroups is trivial you have that $LL'=K$. Now, why does this let you conclude?
- Proceed in a similar way.

Comment: Alex, I think that in your second bullet point, on the third line, one of your quadratic extensions should be $L' = k(\sqrt{v})$ for instance. Right now you have $L$ for both.

Comment: @AdriánBarquero Changed, thank you :)